# Prepare SQL - AJAX return Data

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I need some help setting up DB marker retrieval. I got a bit confused on what exactly to pass back. Here is what I have so far:

data returned:

```
["Chatswood NSW AU","Chippendale NSW AU"]
```

JS:

```
var opdata = [];
    function markers() {
            $.post("id.php", {id: <?php echo $id; ?>})
            .done(function(data) {
                //data is array returned
                opdata = data; //Tried this
                $(opdata) = data; //Tried this
                opdata.push(data); //Tried this
                $.each(data, function(i) { //Tried this
                    opdata.push(data[i]);
                });
            });
            console.log(opdata); //Shows [] empty array regardless what i do
        }
```

PHP:

```
$arr = array();
while (  $selectData -> fetch() ) {
    $arr[] = $address;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

How do I go about retrieving data? None of the above is working.

This is driving me nuts.. should i just $.ajax instead?

Comment: What's the issue? You can't access `opdata` outside of `markers()`?

Comment: Can't get opdata inside of function, outside of function(data)

Comment: Well the data call is async, if you want to use it after the call, use a callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `.done` is asynchronous, meaning that `.done` finishes right away, BEFORE the ajax call is made, and `console.log` is called right after, even if the http call is not finished yet.

Based on your use case and context you can choose between 3 options to return `opdata` back to the caller function:

```
///// OPTION 1: synchronous call
function markersUsingSynchronousCallToAjax() {
    var opdata = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "id.php",
        async: false, // disable asynchronous call to ajax
        data: {id: <?php echo $id; ?>},
        success: function(data) {
            opdata = data;
        }
    })
    return opdata;
}
var opdata = markersUsingSynchronousCallToAjax();
console.log("using a synchronous ajax call", opdata);


///// OPTION 2: callback 
function markersUsingCallback(callback) {
    $.post("id.php", {id: <?php echo $id; ?>})
    .done(function(data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}
markersUsingCallback(function(opdata){
    console.log("using a callback", opdata);
});



///// OPTION 3: promise 
function markersUsingPromise(callback) {
    return $.post("id.php", {id: <?php echo $id; ?>});
}
markersUsingPromise().done(function(opdata){
    console.log("using a promise", opdata);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me give this a try now.

Comment: Thank you for all those examples! Now I have something to work with =]